# Nested enumerated lists with specific numeration

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'm trying to define functional requirements for software in LaTeX. Each requirement needs an ID, so I decided to use `enumitem` to define a list with special labels. It's all fine when it's non-nested, but to avoid duplication I wanted to have nested list with sub-requirements.

I'd like the top level items to have labels like `FR1:` and sublayers like `FR1.1:`

My current approach looks like this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{funcreq}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[funcreq, 1]{label = \textbf{FR\arabic*:}}
\setlist[funcreq, 2]{label* = \arabic*}
```

This is far from ideal, because it results in `FR1:1` instead.

Is it possible to extract the current number from parent label?
Maybe is it possible to edit parent label from child label to remove the colon? (like adding backspace character as the first character in child label)
Or I should forget about it and use something better than `enumitem` for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{funcreq}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[funcreq, 1]{label = \textbf{FR\arabic*:},}
\setlist[funcreq, 2]{label = FR\arabic{funcreqi}.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{funcreq}
\item a
\item b
 \begin{funcreq}
 \item b
 \end{funcreq}
\end{funcreq} 
\end{document}
```

[image]